# How do i resolve this pod install error on flutter?

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods

I can't load all the requested pods apparently there is a problem with these two project dependencies ... "pod upgrade" terminal command results are:

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 10.0.7, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 10.3.0)

    flutter_geofire (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GeoFire (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Database (~> 6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/ios` directory, remove the `Podfile.lock` file.

Then, on terminal, run to this directory:

```
cd ./ios
```

Then run the following command:

```
pod deintegrate && pod repo update && pod install
```

The command is composed of three parts:

- "pod deintegrate" - This command will deintegrate CocoaPods from the project, removing any references to Pods and the Podfile.lock file
- "pod repo update" - This command updates the local copy of the CocoaPods spec repo, which is the source of information about available pods.
- "pod install" - This command installs the pods specified in the Podfile, and creates an Xcode workspace if one does not already exist.

This command is useful when you want to update your project's dependencies and integrate the new version of the Pod without having any conflicts.

Comment: pod deintegrate  and pod repo update was good but pod install : [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: Do you have a Podfile file inside your /ios directory? If not, have you deleted this one? Remember I told you to remove the .lock one. If not the case, try to run `flutter create .`

Comment: ok but now :  `1 error generated.
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/davidedileo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbywtsfagrwhvfflrsbtsbzfkbey/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Sc
    ript-ED0F1B15B9D1183F9A0197B9.sh'`

Comment: Honestly, I've never faced such error. Sorry, I cannot help in such case :/

Comment: Can you help me with this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75225789/how-fix-module-flutter-geofire-not-found ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the pod file inside the ios folder.
2. go to the terminal in path ios ios folder and run command "pod init"
3. manage signin procedure in xcode
4. noy try to run